# How to use Bootstrap tooltip properly with SVG Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

[image]I have a svg object

```
<rect id="SvgjsRect1166" width="21" height="20" fill="#44a340" x="207" y="23" data-count="14" data-date="Sun:07" data-toggle="tooltip" class="cursor-hand" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="tooltip" aria-describedby="tooltip335193"></rect>
```

and have the javascript

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: '.punch' });
```

The tooltip is showing but it showing outside of the rectangle.(.puch is the container div of the svg object ) .how i can adjust position of tooltip

**NB: The svg object creating dynamically using javascript**

Comment: have you tried simply `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`? Where does that show the tooltip?

Comment: Add some screenshots or fiddle will make easier to help @BinsonEldhose

Comment: @SathvikCheela screenshot attached

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n5ux34ta/  @fixed